# Load different component dynamically based on condition

Tags: angular

I have two components. Component A and Component B.

If I choose A from drop down I would like to route to /shop component and load component A into it, if I selected B from drop down I would like to route to /shop route and load component B into it. This is for example useful if you have different payment providers and you have different component structure and you don’t want to route with IFs to /componentA and /componentB.

Now I found that using ComponentFactoryResolver might be the way to go? Am I looking into right direction?

I would also like to avoid if else at any cost based on drop down selection so I will probably use some kind of strategy pattern here.

What would be most elegant way doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Used & follow the same:

- Dynamic component loading http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2-rc-5/